# ESS startup is very slow

Tags: init-file, ess

I recently installed an Ubuntu VM, and I'm working on getting all set up. I've run into a small issue, in that my configuration now takes nearly 30 seconds to start up, where it used to be nearly instant.

I've narrowed the issue down to the `(require 'ess-site)` line in my configuration, but I haven't figured out how to speed it up or replace it. I need to load `ess` there so that I can do my next customization, which is `(ess-toggle-underscore nil)`. Without the `require`, I get errors on that next line. Do I just have to deal with the slow startup time, or is there something I can do to speed this up?

Comment: A shot in the dark: did you bytecompile it? Bytecompiled ELisp code typically loads faster. There's also `eval-after-load` macro you could try, if loading ESS isn't essential at startup (can be delayed until actually used).

Comment: Why don't you use eval-after-load?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't use it because, even after a year and a half of using emacs, I still don't know what I'm doing. Feel free to post an answer, one of you, and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `require` in the init file, I've switched to `eval-after-load` for most things.

So where the line before read:

```el
(require 'ess-site)
(ess-toggle-underscore nil)
```

I now have

```el
(eval-after-load 'ess-site '(ess-toggle-underscore nil))
```