# Why is ESS causing my emacs to start so slowly?

Tags: init-file, ess

For some reason (which I can't understand, I did not change anything) emacs has become very slow - as in 2 min - at startup. I traced it down to the `require` commands of ESS. This is what I have in the `.init` file:

```
(setq load-path (cons "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/ess" load-path))
(require 'ess-site)
(require 'ess-smart-underscore)
(setq ess-default-style 'DEFAULT)
```

`ess-smart-underscore` also loads `ess-site` so eliminating the first `require` does not change anything. From [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13885/ess-startup-is-very-slow/) I tried to use `eval-after-load`, but this does not work:

```
(eval-after-load 'ess-smart-underscore)
```

In general, I don't care to have ESS loading at startup. I'd be happy if it only loads when I open *.R or *.r files, but I'd like a reasonable startup time.
I am running emacs 24.5.1 and ESS 16.04 on Linux. Downgrading to the previous versions of either did not make a difference.

I have now commented everything in `.emacs` except for:

```
(setq load-path (cons "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/ess" load-path))
(require 'ess-site)
```

Then I have reinstalled emacs, ESS, R and updated all the R packages: no difference. I noticed, however, that the first time emacs is launched it is a little bit faster then the following times, which seems odd to me.

Comment: I think you want `(eval-after-load 'ess-smart-underscore '(setq ess-default-style 'DEFAULT))`

Comment: What system are you using? What version of Emacs & ESS? Which of those four lines causes the slow down - probably one of the require calls?

Comment: @npostavs okay, that does not throw an error. however it does not load ESS.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Emacs 24.5.50.1, ESS 16.04 from melpa on Debian Linux. Have you tried running just the four lines above in `emacs -Q`? Maybe something else in your init is interfering. If that's not it, then maybe something is corrupt in your ESS installation, or even in your R installation. I would reinstall both of those if the `emacs -Q` test doesn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: Actually my suggestion appears to be incorrect, http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html says "Use something like `(setq ess-default-style 'DEFAULT)` [...] in your `~/.emacs` equivalent *before* loading ESS"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate cause of this delay is a timeout withing the TRAMP package, that is a dependency of ESS.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=810640

The hang occurs when Emacs spawns ssh processes when initialising the
variable `tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options'.  If your ISP's DNS server
likes to hijack failed lookups to redirect the user to a branded search
engine, these ssh processes hang for a long time before timing out.
This bug affects all Emacs Lisp addons that load TRAMP as part of their
startup...

Comment: Thank you! The link contains a workaround, but the issue seems to be resolved in emacs25.